# html5 video background video on ios

Tags: javascript, ios, html, video

I have the following video that is part of a slider.

```
<div class="slide video-bg">
    <video muted webkit-playsinline playsinline poster="/video/3/4_Marching_band-HD_1080p.jpg">
        <source src="/video/3/4_Marching_band-HD_1080p.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="/video/3/4_Marching_band-HD_1080p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="/video/3/4_Marching_band-HD_1080p.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</div>
```

When the page loads, `play()` is called on the video. On every desktop browser I've tried this works great. But on iOS the video never plays.

I've read https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/ and tried to follow each requirement. I even added the `autoplay` attribute to the video even though I want to control it with js. The video has no audio and is visible when the page loads. Any idea why it won't play on iOS?

Page in question: http://heartland.thinkersites.com/products/

Comment: it won't play because mobile browsers require user interaction in order to play a video. this means the play method must be propagated from an event that has user interaction like "onClick". if you want to play it right away you need to use the autoplay like you tired.

Comment: @KingpinEX  From the webkit.org blog link in my post "video elements will be allowed to play() without a user gesture if their source media contains no audio tracks, or if their muted property is set to true". Also, I mentioned that I tried the autoplay attr and that didn't work either.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your CSS to remove the unsightly play button from iOS devices:

```
                *::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
                  display: none!important;
                  -webkit-appearance: none;
                }

                *::--webkit-media-controls-play-button {
                  display: none!important;
                  -webkit-appearance: none;
                }

                *::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
                  display: none!important;
                  -webkit-appearance: none;
                }
```

Comment: Adding the playsinline attribute seemed to do that. Currently I have no play button. Video does not auto play, that is the issue.